# Density of prime and its finite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

A set $A\subset \mathbb N$ is said to be density zero if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{A\cap [1,n]}{n}=0$ and for any sequence $\langle x_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$, finite sum of the sequence is 
$$
FS\big(\langle x_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty\big)=\{\sum_{j\in J}x_j:J \text{ is a finite subset of } \mathbb N\}.
$$
I already read that the set of prime numbers, $P$ is of density $0$. I wonder whether the density of it's finite sum is $0$ or not?

Comment: Pretty much *every* positive integer is a finite sum of primes.

Comment: According to wiki entry of [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture), the weak version of GC "all odd numbers greater than 7 are the sum of three odd primes" appeared to have been proved in 2013. This means in the worst case, at most $4$ primes is enough. If the strong version of GC is true, then all even number $>2$ is a sum of two primes.....

Comment: @achillehui, it's not clear, to me at least, that GC and its known variants are enough here, since the OP wants finite sums of *distinct* primes.

Comment: @BarryCipra It is true there are some gap between what has been proven and what OP want, but the gap doesn't seem that big. With some clever argument, I'll not be surprised one can deduce what OP want from weak GC. In fact, I strongly suspect the related question on distinct primes has been studied before by the folks working on GC.

Comment: @Barry, I'm sure that every sufficiently large integer is a sum of at most three distinct primes. Large even numbers are (conjecturally) sums of two primes in many ways, at most one of which involves repeated primes, similarly for odd numbers and three primes. There is probably some $n$ for which it's known, unconditionally, that every sufficiently large integer is a sum of at most $n$ distinct primes.

Comment: The question is more-or-less settled by the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535354/is-every-integer-the-sum-of-distinct-prime-numbers also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094725/proof-verification-consequence-of-bertrands-posulate-and-sums-of-primes and a websearch for *sum of distinct primes* will turn up more references.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (and achille hui), I totally agree that it's likely that the gap between GC and/or its known variants can be filled to give what the OP wants. (Indeed, if you assume GC itself, you only need to skip the even numbers that are of the form $2p$, which leaves a set of density at least $1/2$.). But maybe someone should post an actual answer giving an appropriate argument. Also, shouldn't there really be an *easy* proof? (Ah, I see from one of your duplicate links that Bertrand's Postulate and a little induction does the trick.)

Comment: But as the set of primes doesn't really involve 1 in it and also any multiple of prime number can't be written as the sum excluding 1, I couldn't get how the set has a positive density

Comment: @AnindaChakraborty, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example of a multiple of a prime number that can't be written as a sum excluding $1$ (aside from $4$ and $6$)?

Comment: Sorry, in an early comment @achille hui said that any even greater than 2 can be written as the sum, so i just tried 6 and comment..

Comment: @AnindaChakraborty, ah that makes sense. FWIW, I think the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382663/prove-that-every-integer-n-geq-7-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-distinct-primes does a nice job of using Bertrand's Postulate to provide an answer to your question. (I still wonder, though, if your density question could be answered without resorting to a "deep" theorem like BP.)

Comment: Well, @Barry, you need to use *something* about the primes, beyond their infinitude, and Betrand is about the least deep nontrivial result available.